# Change DataStore type

Tags: msbuild, genexus

I am using Genexus X Evolution 1 Up2 and msbuild task for this version. I want to configure generators and Datastores.

I made it for generators and partially for Datastore via:

```
<Target Name="SetupGeneratorAndDatastore">

    <OpenKnowledgeBase Directory="c:\temp\secondApp" />

    <SetGeneratorProperty Generator="genName" Name="SERVLET_DIR" Value="desired" />
    ...
    <SetDataStoreProperty Datastore="dstrName" Name="CS_DBNAME" Value="desired" />
    ...

</Target>
```

How can i change the type of datastore (MySQL for SqlServer or another)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<SetEnvironmentProperty Name="DataSource" Value="SQL Server" />
```

The datastore type is changed via Environmet properties. But only change the type of Default Datastore.

see here http://www.gxopen.com/forumsr/servlet/viewthread?ARTECH,19,175312